# Changing background-color on hover not working properly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the menuOption background-color on hover using JQuery. All my code works fine, the only problem I am having seems to be CSS related. When the background color changes it seems to change the background color of text only as opposed to the  entire div, which is what I want. What I find weird is when I go into the inline CSS of the menuOption element and manually change the background-color it changes the entire divs background color (which is what I want). However, I need to achieve this using JQuery.

Markup Snippet

```
<div class='menuOption' style='list-style-type:none; border:1px solid red; float:left; width:180px; height:20px;'>
<a href='index.php/shop/$sub[cat_url]/' style='color:black;'>
<div class='cat_name'>$sub[cat_title]</div>
</a>
<div class='sub_menu' style='display:none; z-index:100; margin-top:-12px; position:absolute; background-color:#ddd; margin-left:182px; box-shadow:3px 3px 6px #444;'>$itemlist</div>
</div>
```

JQuery Snippet

```
$(".cat_name").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").show();
    $(this, ".menuOption").css("background-color", "#bbb");
});
$(".cat_name").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this, ".menuOption").css("background-color", "#eee");
});
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Could you clean up your example a little bit? Reading html with inline css and no linebreaks hurts my eyes :)

Comment: I dropped this into JFiddle, and it appears to work okay (i.e., it changes the background of the entire div.  I agree with Luke, your code is a little er...hard to read.  Anyway, check out this JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhHUt/

Comment: Thank you for the reply:) grrrr that is bizarre it is working well in jsfiddle.net but not on my website...

Comment: based on your described output the problem likely lies with the border or margin attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrDph/3/

```
$(".cat_name").hover(function() {
    $menuOption = $(this).closest(".menuOption");
    $menuOption.find(".sub_menu").show();
    $menuOption.css("background-color", "#bbb");
},
function() {
    $menuOption = $(this).closest(".menuOption");
    $menuOption.find(".sub_menu").hide();
    $menuOption.css("background-color", "#eee");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Theory: you're not putting your JavaScript in a "do this after the document has loaded" block. That'll look something like this:

```
$.fn.ready(function() {
    $(".cat_name").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").show();
        $(this, ".menuOption").css("background-color", "#bbb");
    });
    $(".cat_name").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this, ".menuOption").css("background-color", "#eee");
    });
});
```

For reference, `$.fn.ready` is another way to say `$(document).ready` (which is faster, I believe).

It could be a separate problem entirely, though.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. I actually do have the $(document).ready in my actual code, I just pasted the snipped ;)

Comment: Well, erm, then I'm not sure. Take a look at the JavaScript console and see what's there.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code

http://jsfiddle.net/jt795/1/

```
$(this, "menuoption") it's not the rightway
```

Code it individually
$(this).css(....)
$("menuoption").css(...)
because $(this) returns object it wont't give a tagname, so you couldn't write like that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Every "menuOption" has the same class name, its simply a div, and there are many of these divs on the page. Its not a 'list', so I need to incorporate 'this' into it somehow to differentiate it from all the other elements with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought for your jQuery:

If you're going to use find() which searched down the DOM, then you should use closest() which searches up the DOM (instead of .parent().parent()). You can put in .closest('div') or .closest('.menuOption'). Then if you decide you need to add another element wrapping the cat name you don't have to add another parent() call. One method call is typically better than multiple.

Also, I'm becoming a big advocate of coffeescript. http://coffeescript.org/. If you're in the mood to learn something a little new, you should look into it. It compiles to javascript and looks pretty much like javascript minus all the brackets, parenthesis and semicolons. Easily readable code is the best code!

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CODE

```
$(".cat_name").hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").show();
  $(this).css("background-color", "#bbb");
  $(".menuOption").css("background-color", "#bbb");
}, function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#eee");
  $(".menuOption").css("background-color", "#eee");
});
```

Comment: If there is more than one item with the class menuOption, it will change the background color of all of them not just the one being hovered over. By the way, you should merge your two answers together.